# Is there any way we can know which partition is assigned for which instance of service in consumer group?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm trying to solve the load-balancing problem using Kafka, I had one scheduler running on one service which has three instances. The problem is when the scheduler runs, all of the instances are running the same schedular. I can't use any external libraries which work with a database. Is there any way we can solve this through Kafka? Can you give me a proper implementation example?

Answer (score 0):

> know which partition

Use a Listener to notify your app of what partitions get assigned.

https://kafka.apache.org/31/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/ConsumerRebalanceListener.html#onPartitionsAssigned(java.util.Collection)

> load-balancing problem using Kafka

Kafka does not "load balance" in the same way as HTTP would. Unclear what you're expecting here.

> when the scheduler runs, all of the instances are running the same schedular

Are you using the same consumer group? If so, only one consumer would get any one message in the topic

Comment: In my case, the producer is the same scheduler, so all the instances are gonna produce messages, and I'll have all messages to consume eventually three messages and three instances and one message each, no problem solved that way. What I want is, if there is any way we can know which partition is gonna take the next published message and I was thinking to take from that partition is the current partition I'll prooceed the message, not otherwise.

Comment: You can decide what partition each record goes to when you produce. Look at the KafkaProducer Javadoc, but your question was about consumer groups, to which I already answered... Your consumers should never need to know which partition a record had been written to